# MySQL procedural developing instead of sending big queries

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Quite theoritical question, but important on a longer developing term:

**Scenario A (general case):**

- I build up my queries on the client side, and send them to the server. (by PHP, Perl, whatever)
- Pros: quicklier development, because the query string is built up only at the client side, and can be modified easily (the code must be modified on the client side). CRUD can be easily developed OO (object oriented).
- Cons: in case of bigger and more similar queries, i have to send a long query strings and in the case of repetition I should better prepare them to save network payload. (e.g. import script/app that executes a lots of INSERT statement).

**Scenario B:**

- I create some frequently used procedures to gain or create data for my tables, which have some general input parameters, and by them build the query string up on the server side.
- Pros: I send a short query string to the server with the parameters, low network payload.
- Cons: the developing takes definitely longer, creating concept for generalizing the queries, client must be aware of the procedures and its versions.

Opinions? Is it completely true/false, what I summed up? somebody had experience with that?

Comment: Have you thought about security issues in either of the scenarios?

Comment: not really in the first round of planning... but filtering by procedures in order to avoid mysql injection would also be a good idea, i guess... because wrapping all the input parameters by procedures can be an easy development enhancement, or not?

Comment: @ALL ANSWERER: my idea is to generate the database manipulation code (ALTER TABLE, CREATE PROCEDURE, etc.), and provide a management backend interface for the (web)app engineer to design them. In that manner the maintainability has the same complexity level in both Scenario A and B, but the location and level of abstraction is not the same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are developing an application, then -- in the end-state -- I think the only queries in the application should be something like `select <list of columns> from view where <whatever>` and the only data manipulation statements should be calls to stored procedures that return appropriate error messages to the application.

In other words, you want to develop an API for the application.  SQL offers an API (`insert`/`update`/`delete`), but I don't think the raw SQL is appropriate for most database applications.

During development, I'm much more flexible.  Putting complex queries on the application side may be needed to solve certain problems, quickly.  They should just be migrated into the database.

Why?  The primary reason is maintainability, and on a number of fronts.  By wrapping all query access into views, you protect the application from changes to the underlying data structure.  After all, things change and user needs grow, and sometimes the data model has to reflect this.

Second, the DBA can see all the queries in one place.  This opens room for improvements, consolidation, simplification, and optimization of the database and the queries.

Putting all the data manipulation into stored procedures allows you to implement business rules *without* triggers.  Triggers can be very tricky, especially when you start having cascading triggers between multiple tables implementing business rules.  This also allows for application-side logging and for more intelligible error messages.

Also, using views and stored procedures provides fairly natural protection against SQL injection -- not totally, but a lot.  But in many databases, you can prevent users from modifying tables directly, while giving them modification access through stored procedures.

Comment: I'd furthermore add that sprocs allow much greater control over data access and auditing.  I often configure my databases to deny direct table access to the application user, forcing it instead to call my sprocs which use elevated privileges but only after checking any access restrictions and performing appropriate audit logging.

Comment: nice guide, i really appreciate it. Every point of view is in that what I needed to consider.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the rationale to use stored procedures is not at all the size of the query string: Even a very long query string will produce negligable network overhead as opposed to the fetch phase if data is returned.

And this is not yet talking of the actual execution of the query: I have yet to see a mysql server, that is bound by network bandwidth, not disk or CPU.

What stored procedures give you is a higher level of abstraction: If you have stored procedures called `CreateFoo()` and `GetFooById()`, your application doesn't need to know, how a `foo` is stored in your DB (including all relational oddities).

This is good for maintenance, and most of all it is good for robustness: If you don't need to know about the table structure involved in a `foo`, your application has no chance to screw it up - e.g. forget about a jointable etc.

In Essence, this means, your DB needs to trust your App less. In many scenarios applications never have the privileges to directly manipulate a table - they may **only** call stored procedures (e.g. Banking)

That said, stored procedures are not a silver bullet. Use the right tool for the job, common sense and a good night's sleep seem to help a lot.

Comment: unfortunately i can not mark to answers as good answers, but i raised you reputation anyway.

Comment: the example with CreateFoo() and GetFooById() is the thought, that I got in order to provide better abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

Two major faults in your initial assumptions.

1. As a matter of fact, every HTTP request carries a lot of HTTP headers with it, up to several kilobytes. So, a query won't be too much a burden. Same with multiple inserts: a small "INSERT INTO t SET" is just a negligible overhead to literal pairs field=value, field=value you have yo have in HTTP request either way.
2. **Have you thought about security issues in either of the scenarios?**

And, JFYI:

> I create some frequently used procedures to gain or create data for my tables, which have some general input parameters, and by them build the query string up on the server side

That's how at least 99% php/mysql web-applications (frankly - web-sites) works. May be they do it for a reason.

Comment: 1. ok, you've got right. In the case of INSERT statements i won't gain speed, but after the abstraction layer is fully implemented on the server side, i do not have to bother with building up queries for linked tables - if the tables are normalized.

e.g. CreateFoo('thisgoesintotable1', 'thisgoesintotable2');